# Работа с классами и текстовыми файлами в заголовочных файлах

Tags: c++

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь создать класс, в котором будут описаны методы для работы с текстовыми файлами: чтение, редактирование, запись и так далее...

Так как методы этого класса хочу использовать в последующих проектах, то делаю это с использованием заголовочных файлов.

**Листинг хиддера MyClasses.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASSES_H_INCLUDED
#define MYCLASSES_H_INCLUDED
#include <fstream>

using namespace:: std;

class MyClass{

private:

     int string_size=0;      

     char input_symbol=0;    

public:

     int check_line_float(ifstream *input_file);

};

#endif // MYCLASSES_H_INCLUDED
```

**Листинг источника к хиддеру MyClasses.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClasses.h"

using namespace::std;

int check_line_float(ifstream *input_file){

     int string_size=0, error_cnt;      

     char input_symbol=0; 

     if(!input_file.is_open()){

       cout << "Cant open file" << endl;

    }else{

        while(input_file>>noskipws>>input_symbol){

            if (input_symbol != '0' &&
                input_symbol != '1' &&
                input_symbol != '2' &&
                input_symbol != '3' &&
                input_symbol != '4' &&
                input_symbol != '5' &&
                input_symbol != '6' &&
                input_symbol != '7' &&
                input_symbol != '8' &&
                input_symbol != '9' &&
                input_symbol != '.' &&
                input_symbol != 32  &&
                input_symbol != 2   &&
                input_symbol != '-'){

                    error_cnt++;

                    cout << "Incorrect input numeric format. Some unknown symbol is detected" << endl;

                    cout << input_symbol << endl;

                    return -1;

                }

                string_size++;
            }

            cout << "Everething is ok" << endl;

            return 0;

        }

 };
```

**Листинг основной программы The_Matrix.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "MyClasses.h"


using namespace::std;

int main(){

    // Сюда компилятор даже не успел дойти

return 0;
}
```

Без использования заголовочных файлов все работает: текстовый файл читается; строка, содержащаяся в нем, проверяется на наличие необходимых символов, как описано в коде.

С ходдерами же ошибок столько, что переписывать их сюда будет дольше кода.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Вот ошибки:

```
   ||=== Build: Debug in The_Matrix (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
   F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.h|11|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
   F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.h|13|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
   F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.cpp||In function 'int check_line_float(std::ifstream*)':|
   F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.cpp|24|error: request for member 'is_open' in 'input_file', which is of pointer type 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|
   F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.cpp|32|error: invalid operands of types 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}' and 'std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)' to binary 'operator>>'|
   F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.cpp|70|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
   ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин, читайте текст ошибок:

```
F:\CodeBlocks\Code_blocks_prj\The_Matrix\MyClasses.cpp|24|error: request for member
```

'is_open' in 'input_file', which is of pointer type 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

Попробуйте заменить . на ->. Вы же с указателем работаете.

Comment: проблемы на этом не закончатся. Тут не только ошибки компиляции(компилятор ясно сообщает о всех ошибках, но и логические ошибки связанные с тем, что например закрытые члены всегда будут иметь нулевое значение, и они никак не используются

Comment: Ну и вообще хидер бесполезен. В cpp нет ни одного упоминания класса MyClass. И более того, доступ к функции check_line_float из The_Matrix.cpp нет. Тут вообще плохо все.